Unity3D - Collision not entering / Detecting
I have a Meteor and a Player object. Both with RigidBody2d and Colliders2d. Meteor collider has "Is Trigger" checked and it has a script with OnCollisionEnter2D() implemented but the collision is not working when the meteor hits player:
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other) {
    Debug.Log(other.gameObject.tag);        
    Destroy(other.gameObject);        
}

}
-Meteor-

-Player-

View


OnCollisionEnter2D is called when the object collides with another solid object, and because the meteor is a trigger, it'll never be called.
Try using OnTriggerEnter2D instead.

You are right. I was following a tutorial and the in there its is using OnTriggerEnter and in my code I put OnCollisionEnter. Lack on attention from my end. Thank you.
